# Degree symbol on LCD

Tags: python, display

Strings' encoding in Python 2.7 is hard to me.

I'd like to show `0°C` on a [display](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/HD44780.pdf). I've found little [manual for my display](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/08/20x4-lcd-module-control-using-python/#comment-725), but

```
    weather = '%s%sC' % (str(temperature), chr(223))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xdf in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Has anyone any ideas how to decode this symbol?

Comment: You'll be way better off posting this on a python forum or [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), where there will be oodles of people who know the answer (I'm not a python user, but I would guess part of the issue is you should be using a `utf8` codec and not an `ascii` one).  General point: this question has nothing specific to do with the pi.  By analogy, just because I have an Acme 5000 laptop does not mean the Acme forum is the best place to ask about string encodings in python.  45 minutes is a long time to wait for an answer to a very basic question.

Comment: The error message says you are trying to use a character that is not in range. It seems like there are only 128 characters and you are saying use character 223.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the chracter set that is programmed into the HD44780. The generic Hitachi has two code pages with a 16x16 matrix which gives you 256 characters per code page and 512 in total.

The actual code that tells the LCD screen which symbol to use might not understand what you are trying to display and throws that error. You most likely need to set the PAGE and Select the character number you are interested in.

[image]
<sup>[* Hitachi HD44780 specification from sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf)</sup>

The error code is saying you supplied it with a character that is out of its range. It does not know how to translate it. This could be cause by Python? Or the Library you are working in. But somewhere you are not supplying the expected value,even though it looks like you are. Possibly caused by UNICODE instead of UTF-8 issues???

Comment: It is caused by python -- `'%s%sC'` is a format string, and it's the last token that's "out of range" because there are only 128 ASCII characters.  You'll need a charset with a range of at least 256 characters, *but also one that uses a single byte for characters 128-256* because the value 223 must be encoded that way (as a literal decimal value, not a codepoint). Unfortunately, UTF-8 uses *2 bytes* for codepoints in that range.  There may an "extended latin" set that uses 256 1 byte values, but **a better idea would be to just pass this as a sequence of bytes, not an encoded string.**

Comment: Ahh yes. So really the code page is set in the 44780 libraries constant or constructor, by the looks of it. Since A01 and A02 use the same Higher and Lower bits. If using CODE A01 the bits need to be `1101 1111` to get a degree sign.

Comment: Based on this answer, I found that this works well enough >>>> "{}ßC".format(temp) <<<<. This is because the character ß in the A02 code page maps onto a Japanese symbol that looks like ° in the A01 code page.